# Where is a typical Linux program installed

Tags: linux, installation

I mean not just the binary, but its libraries, config files and data (strictly speaking all files). Also when I download a package where is it best to extract it. If I move these files will the app be corrupted?

Comment: On non-mobile OSes, "app"s are called either programs or applications. I personally hate that word already..

Comment: That was a really good question btw, Tichomir.

Comment: @Bora: "app" is just shortened form of "application", and was in use way before the smartphone craze.

Comment: @grawity: I'd like to see your source, primarily to deepen my hate in its history.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Most programs follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (`man hier`): libraries go to `/usr/lib`, configuration files to `/etc`, static data to `/usr/share`, and so on.

  Some self-contained programs put all data in `/opt/<program>/`.
- `.deb`/`.rpm` packages are not supposed to be unpacked manually – they should be handled by the apropriate program, `dpkg` or `rpm`.

  If you have only the source code in a tarball, you must extract it to a temporary location (somewhere to `/tmp` or `$HOME`). The rest, including installation is usually handled by the Makefile (by running `make install`); see FHS above.

Comment: Note that FHS version 3 is currently in progress, and the layout may change somewhat.

Comment: And indeed, once you have used the `.deb` or `.rpm` file, it is no longer needed.  If I download a random `.deb` file, I usually download it to `/tmp`, or my home directory if I may need it again on a different box. When `apt` downloads a package, it is stored in `/var/cache/apt` from where it will eventually be cleaned out.

Answer (score 3):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) describes the directory layout used on Linux.